# Sending large files in java

Tags: java, networking

How to send large files (2-3 GB) over the network using sockets? I have written a socket program which sends files from the server to client. But it is taking a very long time to send even 300 MB.

Comment: How fast is your network connection? Calculate how long you could expect it to take to send that amount of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine whether the network is the bottleneck and compress the files before sending if it is. Use [`DeflaterOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html) in the sender and [`InflaterInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html) in the receiver. (Don't do this if the files are already compressed; many media formats include compression.)

Comment: It should be noted that most forms of compression (including *deflate*) would be rather useless on certain file formats that have already been compressed, such as MP3 audio or video files. Using compression blindly on such files is ill-advised...

Comment: @thkala While it could be useless, it is unlikely to make it significantly worse.

Comment: @thkala: good point, added that to the answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: true, although it can hurt performance in larger applications. Just the other day I "fixed" a performance issue in a web server that used to deflate .mp4 files before sending them over the LAN. Two or three simultaneous downloads were enough to occupy both allocated processors and bring the server to its knees...

Comment: Am trying to send a 3 GB movie from one laptop to another. Since its in the .avi format, is there no point in compressing it?

Comment: AVI is compressed. You can try compressing it with gzip or 7-zip to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @larsmans: From my experience, compressed media files may actually be shrank by about 1-2% by generic compression algorithms. In my opinion, though, this kind of space gain is not worth the cost and complexity of (de)compression. That said, AVI is merely a container, not a codec. An `.avi` file could easily contain raw uncompressed video that may be highly compressible even with generic lossless algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Large files can take a long time depending on the upload speed of your Internet connection.

Say you have broadband with an upload speed of 128 Kb. (Your download speed doesn't matter)

This will transfer up to 16 KB (kilo-bytes) per second.  This means 1 MB should take over a minute and 1 GB should take over 16 hours.